# HDInsight-Kafka cluster access from Azure function

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to create Hdinsight-kafka cluster using below Microsoft doc
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/kafka/apache-kafka-get-started

No issues with above steps, later created azure function app using below instructions
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/kafka/apache-kafka-azure-functions

This is where I need some help as connection to Kafka is not establish due to virtual network, virtual gateway configuration

Error- broker not found

Answer (score 0):

By default, the azure functions you create will be outside your VNET [where you broker sits]. For you to connect your broker to your AZ Functions, you need to bring the function into your VNET.

Below is the article for this: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet

Comment: Please show some explanation and/or code to support your link. SO is not a bouncing platform for Google.